# Erro ao utilizar a library listViewVariants -Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:ListViewVariants:15fe3904fd

Tags: android

Estou a tentar utilizar a biblioteca [ListViewVariants](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1406) como está no site *The Android Arsenal*, mas não estou a conseguir.

Compilo e adiciona o *Maven* da biblioteca quando faço o *Sync* não funciona, dá erro:

```
Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:ListViewVariants:15fe3904fd
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Código:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
           apply plugin: 'findbugs'
           url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
        }

        maven {
           url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
```

---

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['json-simple-1.1.1.jar'])
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile 'com.tonicartos:superslim:0.4.9'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:ListViewVariants:15fe3904fd'

}
```

Comment: O que é que não está a conseguir?

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta e coloque o `log` de erro. Se puder colocar o código também ajudará